# A reference variable is being treated as both unused and undefined. Why?

Tags: javascript, angular, variables, reference

I'm using references in my HTML code to pass the value of an input into a JavaScript function. However, while one reference variable (`#options`) works fine, the other (`#current`) is marked in one place as "unresolved/undefined" and in its declaration as "unused." I can't figure out what the difference is between them and why this is happening.

I know it's not an issue with duplicity of reference, because `current` works fine if it's placed in a (click) event in its own input element; however, it can't be an issue of scope either, because the inputs reference `options` just fine. So why can't the icon functions reference `current` in return?

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="maxInstalls">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Max Installs</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let profile">
          <input #current (click)="showDiv(options)" class="hiddenInput" type="number" min="0"
                 *ngIf="(profile.maximumInstalls > 0)" value="{{profile.maximumInstalls}}">
          <input #current (click)="showDiv(options)" class="hiddenInput" type="number" min="0"
                 *ngIf="(profile.maximumInstalls == 0)" value="">
          <div #options hidden="true">
            <mat-icon (click)="changeMaxInstalls(current, profile, options)">done</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon (click)="hideDiv(options)">clear</mat-icon>
          </div>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
```

I expect `changeMaxInstalls()` to pass the `current` variable into the function; however, it throws an error that `current` is undefined. Also, in my IDE, the declarations of the `#current` references are flagged as "unused local variables." `showDiv()` and `hideDiv()` reference `options` without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you have two elements with the #current tag.

You can achieve the same by using a single element with a ternary:

```
<input #current (click)="showDiv(options)" class="hiddenInput" type="number" min="0"  value="{{(profile.maximumInstalls > 0) ? profile.maximumInstalls: ''}}">
```

Comment: I have no idea why this works, because just deleting one of the input lines with the #current tag to ensure uniquity didn't fix the problem. But this simplifies the code and... somehow... fixes the unused variable issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same [Template Reference Variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars) for two elements (`#current)`. These variables are intended to be unique across an entire template. The Angular docs say the following in the post I linked:

> The scope of a reference variable is the entire template. Do not define the same variable name more than once in the same template. The runtime value will be unpredictable.

Comment: As I said, I know it's not an issue with duplicity of reference, because current works fine if it's placed in a (click) event in its own input element. It never throws an error about them needing to be unique—just that they don't exist.

Comment: You did say that you *know* it's not an issue of duplicity of reference, then explained how you *know* that. I wrote my answer because I question your means of ascertaining the facts; The only way you could really *know* that this is not the issue is by temporarily removing the duplicate reference variables, which is not something you mentioned doing. Also, the docs do not say anything about throwing an error they say that the runtime value will be unpredictable. Nonetheless I am happy your issue is now resolved.

Comment: Thanks. I did try removing one of the inputs, but it didn't work. Still not entirely sure why this all occurred, but for now I guess I can shelve it.